# PowerAutomate - customised email when New Item is added - But with default image/msg below

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I really like how the default notification looks like for a List notification.
Except I would like to add a customised message for it.

Is there a way to add the below dynamic image in a customised power automate workflow?
(I am not asking how to create a workflow, I've already done that but it comes out as plain text with a link - but not fancy looking like below)

My objective is "Customised messages" + default looking "Title + Link below" with the "Go To Item" button.

[image]

Comment: You can use HTML in send an email action body to add image or customized text with styling. If you want the fix/static and same image for all emails, convert the email to base64 type and use it directly in your flow email action.